# JavaFX TextPane doesn't show updated text

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Pane (all code below) which contains a HBox with 2 subPanes, VisualPane and TextPane. When someone presses `ENTER` or `SPACE` I want the program to print "Enter pressed." and "Space pressed." respectively. When `ESCAPE` is pressed I want the application to shut down.

TextPane consists of a Pane with a private TextArea. With the method `push(String message)` the TextArea is cleared, and afterwards filled with the new message.

However, when you press either Enter or Space nothing happens. "Text" is printed in the console once, no matter how many times you press the button. Whenever Escape is pressed the program still exits, however.

Why does the `push()` method "freeze" the TextArea?

Code:

```
public class GamePane extends Pane {

  private VBox content;
  private HBox textBox;

  private VisualPane visualPane;
  private TextPane textPane;

  public GamePane(){
    initialize();
  }

  private void initialize(){
    this.content = new VBox();
    getChildren().add(content);
    this.textBox = new HBox();

    this.visualPane = new VisualPane();
    this.textPane = new TextPane();

    content.getChildren().add(visualPane);
    content.getChildren().add(textBox);
    textBox.getChildren().add(textPane);

    this.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
      switch (e.getCode()){
        case ENTER:
          this.textPane.push("Button pressed.");
          break;

        case SPACE:
          this.textPane.push("Button pressed.");
          break;

        case ESCAPE:
          Platform.exit();
          break;
      }
    });
  }
}

public class TextPane extends Pane {

  private TextArea textArea;

  public TextPane(){
    initialize();
    push("Text");
  }

  private void initialize(){
    this.textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setMinWidth(Constants.width);
    textArea.setMinHeight(Constants.height * 4 / 11);

    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 3em;");

    getChildren().add(textArea);
  }

  public void push(String message){
    textArea.clear();
    textArea.setText(message);
    System.out.println("Text");
  }
}
```

PS:

GamePane has an HBox Textbox for content that is to be added.

Comment: Please create and post a [MCVE]. (Otherwise everyone is basically forced to guess.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `this.setOnkeyPressed(..)` to `this.setOnKeyReleased(..)`.

You may also have to add `this.requestFocus();` if your node doesn't have focus when your program starts.

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class GamePane extends Pane
{

    private VBox content;
    private HBox textBox;

    private VisualPane visualPane;
    private TextPane textPane;

    public GamePane()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        this.content = new VBox();
        getChildren().add(content);
        this.textBox = new HBox();

        this.visualPane = new VisualPane();
        this.textPane = new TextPane();

        content.getChildren().add(visualPane);
        content.getChildren().add(textBox);
        textBox.getChildren().add(textPane);

        this.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {//Change here!
            switch (e.getCode()) {

                case ENTER:
                    this.textPane.push("Enter pressed.");
                    break;

                case SPACE:
                    this.textPane.push("Space pressed.");
                    break;

                case ESCAPE:
                    System.out.println("escaped pressed");
                    Platform.exit();
                    break;
            }
        });

        this.requestFocus();//Change here!
    }
}
```

**Do you also know why OnKeyPressed behaves differently from OnKeyReleased?**

> This answer is from the
>   [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html).
>
> "Key typed" events are higher-level and generally do not depend on the
>   platform or keyboard layout. They are generated when a Unicode
>   character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about
>   character input. In the simplest case, a key typed event is produced
>   by a single key press (e.g., 'a'). Often, however, characters are
>   produced by series of key presses (e.g., SHIFT + 'a'), and the mapping
>   from key pressed events to key typed events may be many-to-one or
>   many-to-many. **Key releases are not usually necessary to generate a
>   key typed event, but there are some cases where the key typed event is
>   not generated until a key is released** (e.g., entering ASCII
>   sequences via the Alt-Numpad method in Windows). No key typed events
>   are generated for keys that don't generate Unicode characters (e.g.,
>   action keys, modifier keys, etc.).

Comment: Strangely, this worked. Do you also know why OnKeyPressed behaves differently from OnKeyReleased?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it displays `Text` in the console once is due to the `push(String message)` method being called in the `TextPane` constructor.

The problem is most likely due to the `GamePane` not being the focused `Node` in the scene graph.

To fix this you can make the `GamePane` request focus after the `GamePane` has been added to the `Scene`. e.g.:

```
public class GameApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
        GamePane gamePane = new GamePane();        
        Scene scene = new Scene(gamePane);
        gamePane.requestFocus();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```